# Microsoft Lync 2011 keep asking keychain password prompt on each login in macOS

Tags: macos, lync, lync-2013, lync-2010

> Microsoft Lync wants to use OC_KeyContainer_username@company.com. Please enter the keychain password prompt appeared.

The curious thing is that the keychain prompt does not accept the user’s current login password.

How to remove this popup from appearing randomly

Answer (score 0):

To Fix Lync Issue

1. Go to Folder Path

   > **~/Library/Keychains/**
2. Delete OC_KeyContainer__first.last\@domain.com-db" file
3. Quit Lync, re-launch Microsoft Lync Tool

This will fix Popup from appearing randomly